# ios 8 Top bar app using your current location it navigate to wrong application

Tags: ios8, location, notification-bar

In one of my projects I have navigated the user to the Google Maps application, and for that I have used call-back URL, and I have made my application URL for navigating from Google Map to my application. When my app is open and the user clicks on the blue bar at the top, it works perfect, but when my app is not running and some other application using device location and the user clicks on blue bar at top it navigates to my application. I don't know what's wrong happening here - does anybody know the solution?